# How to express "is null" sql syntax in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

How can I express "IS NULL" sql syntax in Linq to Sql?

```
Where(r => (r.Level1.Equals(l[1] == "" ? null : l[1]))
```

In the above code linq to sql converts the linq expression into the following sql which is not what I want.

```
@p1=NULL
```

I want my linq to be converted into the following sql

```
@p1 is null
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you show all the sql generated ? Do you really have `WHERE @p1=null` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (l[1] == "")
    Where(r => (r.Level1 == null));
else
    Where(r => (r.Level1 == l[1]));
```

If you use the ternary operator the expression evaluator will find that it's a expression returning a string, cause of this it'll use the = operator.

Comment: If I do the following it's the same.                                 Where(r => (r.Level1 == (l[1] == "" ? null : l[1])) Still not producing the desired sql

Comment: How is the Level1 property declared? It's `int` or `int?`?. For nullable database fields, you must use nullable types.

Comment: In the dbml designer, the Level1 property is declared as Nullable in the properties windows?

Comment: @Neo Your example is **NOT** the same as fhelwanger's.  His example should work, but yours will not.